# adColony Expecting libadcolony.so in libs directory but it was not found

Tags: android, ads, interstitial, adcolony, rewardedvideoad

I'm trying to implement reward video with adColony but i'm getting trouble
In folder app/libs i have added libadcolony.so also adcolony.jar version 3.0.7 in lib folder

in my activity

```
     AdColony.configure(this, appOptions, "app83c6f9efcc25******",    
    "vzf20fd3c78687******");
    AdColonyAdOptions options = new AdColonyAdOptions()
            .enableConfirmationDialog(true)
            .enableResultsDialog(true);


    AdColonyRewardListener listener = new AdColonyRewardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReward(AdColonyReward reward) {
            /** Query the reward object for information here */
            gagner3Piece();
        }
    };
```

i also try this:

```
   /** Set reward listener for your app to be alerted of reward events */
    AdColony.setRewardListener(listener);
    AdColonyInterstitialListener AdColonyInterstitialListener = new   
    AdColonyInterstitialListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFilled(AdColonyInterstitial   
       adColonyInterstitial) {
            rewardAdColonyInterstitial =  adColonyInterstitial;

        }
    };
    AdColony.requestInterstitial("vzf20fd3c7868742bfaa", 
  AdColonyInterstitialListener, options);
```

I have this erros :

```
   E/AdColony [ERROR]: Expecting libadcolony.so in libs directory but it was    
   not found.
   I/AdColony [INFO]: Configuring AdColony
   E/AdColony [ERROR]: The AdColony API is not available while AdColony is   
   disabled.
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK-3/issues/1

Comment: thanks for your response but i already tried their solution (Removed:

~/.gradle/
project/.gradle
project/app/build

)

Comment: need to remove ~/.gradle/
project/.gradle
project/app/build and also invalidate caches/restart and disabled instant run as a precaution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add

```
 android {
/** Any other configurations here */

sourceSets {
 main {
  jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
  }
 }
}
```

see from here https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-Android-SDK-3/wiki/Project-Setup